# hello i am using Realm in my project but when i run my project its gives me a crash

Tags: java, android, realm

Hello i have an error when i integrate the Realm Database in my project and I am using realm version 10.11.0 but when I run my project in device its throwing me the error in this line

```
Realm.getInstance(config)
```

This is my Initialise method

```
public static Realm getRealmInstance() {
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    return realm;
}
```

and here I used Realm Object Like This

```
Realm.init(this);
rChatDb = Helper.getRealmInstance();
```

Please tell me why my app is crash the crash report is

2022-08-17 15:47:34.586 11047-11047/com.Roaming.forworld E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been thrown: Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
- Type 'Attachment' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'AttachmentList' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'Chat' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'Group' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'LogCall' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'Message' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'MessageNew' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'MyString' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'Status' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'StatusImage' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'StatusImageList' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'StatusImageNew' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'StatusNew' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'User' appears more than once in the schema.
- Type 'solochat' appears more than once in the schema.
2022-08-17 15:47:34.865 11047-11047/com.Roaming.forworld E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: I cant speak about Realm in general, but this error is telling you that your database has already been created, and you are doing something else to try and create it again.

Comment: but i am creating this instanse only one time